# Better Alternatives for Canny algorithm in Edge Detection?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Canny edge algorithm has 5 stages, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)

```
1. Apply Gaussian filter to smooth the image in order to remove the noise
2. Find the intensity gradients of the image
3. Apply non-maximum suppression to get rid of spurious response to edge detection
4. Apply double threshold to determine potential edges
5. Track edge by hysteresis: Finalize the detection of edges by suppressing all the other edges that are weak and not connected to strong edges.
```

This algorithm was originally developed for antiasymmetric edges $(f(x) = - f(-x)$, where the true edge point is at $x = 0$) such as ridge, roof and step edges, discussing [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1335907/17474) about visualization of these edegs. 
(Source Academic Press, Handbook Imaging Processing Analysis) 
They say only that *requirements for reliable performance are good detection and good localization*.

- Good detection means that a true edge is highly likely to be a detected and that the likelihood of detecting an edge where there is none is low.
- Good localization means that the error in the location of a detected edge relative to that of the true edge should be small.

In summary

> Canny developed mathematical forms for the criteria for low error rate and
>   good localization and showed that there is a trade-off between the two
>   that dictates a unique shape for the impulse response of the optimal
>   detector.

### Canny algorithm and Central Limit Theorem

It assumes the same assumptions to all data sets. 
If Central Limit Theorem holds for the data sample, you include two such samples in one measurement. 
The average of the result will be normally distributed because Canny algorithm cannot affect it, since it applies to all data sets.

Canny algorithm follows the maximum value. 
This may cause it go side tract, for instance here of the paper `Optical quality assurance of GEM foils` by T. Hilden et al:

[image]

### Possible defects in Canny algorithm

There are some situations which cause me systematic error. 
I think some disturbances/defects in the corners of images may cause some systematic deviation in Canny algorithm. 
This is what I do not understand and cannot specify better.

How can use estimate the situations when Canny algorithm fails?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your title asks if there's a better algorithm than Canny's but the body of your post asks how and when to use Canny. And I'm not sure what you mean by how to use an algorithm. You use it by implementing it and giving it data.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I updated the body. There may be some situations with borders of pictures which cause Canny to fail. I do not understand this but it seems to be occurring.

Comment: this involves analysis of your cases (did you actually apply it to some data?), and there is massive existing published research on edge detection algorithms. all edge detection algorithms are subject to weakness because they are basically AI algorithms. in short they fail when the images are "indistinct/ blurry/ noisy." also your example is not in grayscale, doesnt the algorithm run in grayscale? so one might use variants that also take into acct color boundaries. suggest further [chat]. try also [graphicdesign.se] and [dsp.se]